# Tag merge: [powersave] vs. [power-management]

Tags: discussion, tag-synonym-request

I asked a question on power saving: [Disable Wi-Fi on GA-F2A88XN-WIFI motherboard?](https://superuser.com/questions/990379/disable-wi-fi-on-ga-f2a88xn-wifi-motherboard/990381)

I noticed there are separate tags
for [powersave](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/powersave) and [power-management](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/power-management). 
Is there any reason not to make the former a synonym of the latter?

Answer (score 2):

There are only 21 questions tagged [powersave](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/powersave) (all-time),
and four of them are already (also) tagged [power-management](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/power-management). 
Also, [powersave](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/powersave) has no tag wiki. 
This seems like a good candidate for merging.